# Can I use a generator expression to print key,value pairs of a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, generator-expression

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
dictlist = [{'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2'}, {'key3':'value3', 'key4':'value4'}]
```

I currently print key, value pairs like this:

```
for d in dictlist:
  for key in d:
    print .format('{} ---> {}').format(key,d[key])
```

How would I use a generator expression to reduce the lines of code?

Edit: I'm trying to familiarize myself with generator expressions, not just reduce the lines of code!

Comment: Why would you? Is it not working?

Comment: Just want to see if I can improve on it.

Comment: You're only printing the value though.

Comment: 1. Don't shadow `dict`. 2. Otherwise it seems fine; a one-liner would probably be less readable.

Comment: Edited to correct @Nils_M's point.

Comment: I would imagine using a generator would complicate what you have, not simplify it.

Comment: The goal of this question is not clear, and it is likely to produce a lot of opinion-based answers (including my rant below). If you want to get familiar with generator expressions, just practice using them in the normal cases. You will find plenty of valid use cases for them in time, without trying to force them to do wonky stuff like I/O.

Comment: Edited to not shadow dict. Sorry, I missed that.

Comment: @machineyearning the goal is to understand if this is possible using a generator expression. Or is that too vague?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [python docs on expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html). These are all things that just represent values of one sort or another, of various complexity. They are not side-effect inducing things (like I/O) or transformations on mutable data. Generator **expressions** are, as the name implies, just another kind of expression.

Reducing lines of code is not the intended purpose of generator expressions. Beyond their primary usefulness of "memory efficiency and lazily computed values" (thanks commenter below) a big part of their purpose is to make your code more concise and readable by making iterators a more accessible kind of atomic value. If you're making your code less readable, you're probably using generator expressions incorrectly.

In particular generator expressions seem to me tightly linked with the **functional paradigm** of python programming. They yield values as you would expect from a mathematically defined series, like `the generator yielding all the Fibonacci numbers` for a example. With this functional paradigm in mind, *using generators specifically to produce side-effects is probably a **code smell***.

To put it positively the **right way** to use generator expressions is probably to have them doing a single well-defined transformation on one element of an iterable data set at a time, and yielding that transformed data afterwards. This fits in with the functional paradigm: a function takes in a value, returns a value, and has no side-effects.

You could possibly use a generator **function** to refactor this code in an interesting way which would allow you to print successive elements by iterating through the generated elements. Like so:

```
def my_printer(dictlist):
    for d int dictlist: # renamed to not shadow dict
        for key in dict:
            print .format('{} ---> {}').format(key,dict[key])
            yield
```

Then you could print elements like:

```
>>> p = my_printer(dictlist)
>>> p.next()
'some stuff 1'
>>> p.next()
'some stuff 2'
```

Etc.

That's not really what you asked for though.

To answer your question more directly, if you leave the `print` statement out of it, you could get something that looks like a flattening of your nested `for` loops:

```
>>> (('{} ---> {}').format(k,v) for d in dictlist for k,v in d.items())
```

Or actually since `(k,v)` is just a tuple you're passing in the same order, you can use the splat operator `*` to unpack it directly as parameters into your `format` call:

```
>>> (('{} ---> {}').format(*p) for d in dictlist for p in d.items())
```

Finally, you may wish to remove the intermediate list creation of `d.items()` by using the `iteritems` function instead:

```
>>> (('{} ---> {}').format(*p) for d in dictlist for p in d.iteritems())
```

then print the result with a regular for loop though:

```
>>> for x in _:
    print x


key2 ---> value2
key1 ---> value1
key3 ---> value3
key4 ---> value4
```

Comment: I'd also add that one of the primary purposes of generators is *memory efficiency* and *lazily computed values*.

Comment: @machineyearning seeing them refactored as a function makes sense. However, writing them as a single expression is something I struggle with. Like you said, I should practice more.

Would using the generator function make the operation quicker? I thought when looping through the list, and then the keys in the dictionary only a single element would be evaluated at a time.

Comment: No, the generator function would not be quicker. It would just be a different way of writing it to allow you to print elements from your `dictlist` one at a time. You could definitely package up your formatted strings ahead of time though, and writing a generator expression would in fact be more memory efficient than putting them in a `list`. I'll add that at the end. Still, keep the `print` statements out of it.

Comment: @TheStupidEngineer I've added some examples of different ways you can use generator expressions to pack up your data.

Answer (score 2):

There would be no real benefit to making your code horizontal instead of vertical, but you can do so as follows:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from itertools import imap
print(*(' ---> '.join(imap(str, item)) for dic in dictlist for item in dic.iteritems()), sep='\n')
```

Result:

```
key2 ---> value2
key1 ---> value1
key3 ---> value3
key4 ---> value4
```

Note that the `map()` is for converting non-string elements into strings so that they can be joined with `join()`. If you are sure that the keys and values will always be strings, you can simply use `' ---> '.join(item)` instead.

Comment: I'd love to hear what is not helpful or wrong about my answer to make it deserve a downvote. That way I can improve my answer!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but `.items()` and `.map()` defeat benefits of a generator. Use `.iteritems()` and `imap(..)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Umm, what you have is probably the most readable version. I'd probably go with it.

But if you want a more compact version, how about:

```
>>> dictlist = [{'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2'}, {'key3':'value3', 'key4':'value4'}]
>>> list((k,v) for d in dictlist for k,v in d.iteritems())
[('key2', 'value2'), ('key1', 'value1'), ('key3', 'value3'), ('key4', 'value4')]
```

Note: Outermost `list` is just a place-holder. You should call put a function call in its place.

Comment: If you're going to wrap a generator expression in `list`, why not use a list comprehension in the first place?

Comment: The outermost list is a placeholder. The OP should be able to use it as a generator. Let me make that edit.

Comment: @Thrustmaster nice! Would you mind explaining how I can understand your line of thinking please?

Comment: @Thrustmaster hasn't this expression now turned my list of dictionaries into a list of tuples?

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to, you can iterate over a generator expression that prints the stuff itself, and just discard what you iterate over:

```
for _ in (print('{} ---> {}'.format(key,dict[key])) for dict in dictlist for key in dict):
    pass
```

I really don't see a reason to do this, ever, though, it is not very readable. It assumes Python 3, or `from __future__ import print_function`, so you can use `print` in an expression.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a generator expression and `itertools` to one-line it.

```
from itertools import chain, imap

print '\n'.join('{} ---> {}'.format(k,v) for k, v in chain.from_iterable(d.iteritems() for d in dictlist))
```

`d.itervalues()` returns a generator of all the values in each dictionary.  `itertools.chain` takes all those generators, and flattens them into a single generator.  The `itertools.imap` function converts all your values to strings, so they can be printed.  Those values are then fed to the `.join` method which puts a newline between each value and prints it.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3  Oops, forgot to use `chain.from_iterable` instead of `chain`

Comment: Now it doesn't generate a traceback, but it only prints the values, without the keys.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yeah, the question originally asked for just the values.  I updated it once the OP updated the question with the new syntax.  Considering you answered the question the same way originally, you should know that.